# Creating a user in Firebase

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-authentication, laravel-8

I have a Laravel 8 project I'm working on right now. In this project there is a **create button** that is used to register users who have applied for registration. When this button is pressed, a record is created in the DB normally, but this record must also be created in Firebase. That's why I wrote a code like the one below in the function that works when that button is pressed.

**CreatorController-create function**

```
public function create(Request $request){

        $application = null;
        $subscriber = null;
        if($request->application_id!=null){
            $application = CreatorApplicationForm::findorfail($request->application_id);
            $subscriber = User::where([['email','=',$application->email],['role_id','=',4]])->get()->first();

            $auth = app('firebase.auth');
            $uid = User::where(['user_id', '=', $auth->user_id])->get()->first();
            $displayName = User::where(['name', '=', $auth->name])->get()->first();
            $email = User::where(['email', '=', $auth->email])->get()->first();

            $userProperties = [
                'uid' => $uid,
                'displayName' => $displayName,
                'email' => $email, 
            ];

            $createdUser = $auth->createUser($userProperties);
        }

        return view('admin.creators.create',['application' => $application,'subscriber' => $subscriber]);

    }
```

This is how I did it but still no recording in Firebase. How should I write the code in this case?